# Vertical align CSS not working

Tags: css, alignment

I have a large div at 100% width, with a smaller div inside at 1086px;

I am trying to get the small div to be centered horizontally and it's content vertically centered.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:0; padding:0;
            }

            .wrapper {
                width:100%;
                height:446px;
                background:red;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            .inner {
                width:1086px;
                height: 446px;
                background: yellow;
                margin: 0px auto;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner">asd</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertical-centered is just working for table-cells. If you want to horizontally align, you should use display:table-cell; 
Try this code;
 http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/rVRONG

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 446px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.inner {
  display: table;
  width: 1086px;
  height: 446px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.center {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. Show well formatted code for the OP to try. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: it works ! one more thing: can i make the inner div stay fixed on its center position after page load ? i mean, if i resize the window, i want the element to stay fixed, not to move( they move only on Y );

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1086px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  /* margin: 0px auto;
  vertical-align:middle; */

  /* If you can use flexbox
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  */
}

/* If you can't */

.inner > p {
  margin: 0;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translateY(100%);

  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box like this:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:446px;
    background:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.inner {
    width:1086px;
    height: 446px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0px auto;
    vertical-align:middle;     
    display: flex;          /*added*/
    align-items: center;    /*added*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>here the content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the snippet in Full Page.

[Check this out for full information](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background)